# Relation between package and a sub package in Java

Tags: java, package

Can anyone please let me know the relation between a package and a sub package in java?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64018076/1108305

Answer (score 10):

There is no relation between packages and subpackages. It is just a hierarchical structure for the convenience of a developer and has no further meaning to Java itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between them.
package com.stackoverflow in java code just like com/stackoverflow in your operating system.
I'm sorry,my English is poor,beg your parden.

Answer (score -1):

Relation between the package and a sub-package in Java

As Mark Rotteveel said It is just a hierarchical structure for the convenience of a developer

If you're asking about the relationship between them we might say that parent and child relationship.

A **package** is like a folder. In Java containing a group of related classes, interfaces, enumeration, and annotation.

**Sub-package** is nothing but defined inside of another package.

A package may have many sub-packages inside it.

We use packages to avoid name conflicts and to organize your code better, making access easy.

Define package in java:(package must be in the first code of your code)

```java
package packagename;
package packagename.subpackagename;
```

**import packages in java:**

```java
import packagename.classname; or import packagename.*;
import packagename.subpackagename.classname; or import packagename.subpackagename.*;
```

**Predefined sub-packages in java:**

```java
import java.util.*;
```

here java is a package and util is a sub-package ( lang,net,util,awt,SQL)

How to run package in notepad

```
javac packagename\subpackagename\programname.java
javac packagename.subpackagename.programname
```