# What about using import java.* for using all sub-packages under the package 'java'?

Tags: java

```
import java.*;
```

Why cannot I do this import? Instead of importing all classes in a particular sub-package of the package 'java', I tried to import all the sub-packages under the the 'java' package.

How can I import all the built-in classes?

Comment: There is no way in Java to recursively import all subpackages.

Comment: [There is not really such a thing as a _sub_ package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847568/relation-between-package-and-a-sub-package-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `import some.example.Type;` is only to import types not the packages. `import some.example.*;` means you're importing all the Types contained inside `some.example` package not the other packages inside it.

This is because import means the code of that file will be available for your program at run time and package itself doesn't contain any code. It contains files which have the code.

That's why you can't import all the built-in code in a single import statement. At max you can import in a single statement is all the code available in different files within a package and you know the way `import some.example.*;`

Comment: your explanation is satisfactory to me ... so the import is used to import only the classes , interfaces inside a package  ... but how can I import all the classes and Types with a single import statement .. what if I dont want to use multiple import statement ??

Comment: by using import some.example.*; It will import all the classes and Types within some.example package in a single import statement.

Comment: What if I want all the classes and Types within that some package

Comment: Didn't get your question?

Answer (score 12):

There is no such thing as sub-package in java.

`java.util.stream` is not a sub-pacakge of `java.util`.

Therefore `import java.util.*` doesn't import the classes of `java.util.stream`.

To import all the built in classes, you have to import them one package at a time. It's a better practice, though, to only import the classes that you actually need.

Comment: what I mean by "sub-package" , was "Package within a Package"

Comment: @RSMuthuKumaran sub-package is just for showing hierarchy...every package is different in java

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) on Oracle docs, under the heading **Apparent Hierarchies of Packages**:

> At first, packages appear to be hierarchical, but they are not. For
>   example, the Java API includes a `java.awt` package, a `java.awt.color`
>   package, a `java.awt.font` package, and many others that begin with
>   `java.awt`. However, the `java.awt.color` package, the `java.awt.font`
>   package, and other `java.awt.xxxx` packages are not included in the
>   `java.awt` package. The prefix `java.awt` (the Java Abstract Window
>   Toolkit) is used for a number of related packages to make the
>   relationship evident, but not to show inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wildcard when importing classes may clutter your classes namespace so if you'll have a class named `ClassA` in more then one import (e.g. import `com.example1.*` and import `com.example2.*` where `ClassA` is defined in both and you need only the implementation in `com.example1`) you will have a conflict so only import what you really need to use.

Most IDEs allows you to easily organize your imports so only the classes that you really need to use will be imported

Answer (score 0):

It is not like what you think, consider when you want to use `ChannelHandler` interface you could do either `import io.netty.channel.*;` or `import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;` but you cant use `import io.netty.*;` and that why you cant `import java.*;`

Answer (score 0):

You can import java.util.* it work fine but when you import specific class instead of all class it take less time in importing but if you are importing too many classes from same package you can import all classes using package.* and it takes less time for jvm to fetch instead of taking one by one.

**By convention you can use import package.* if you are using too many classes from same package.**

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because Java by design is divided into different packages. This way you can't pollute your namespace with all the classes that exist, and you have to actually specify what classes in which namespace you intend to use.

In java, packages don't relate to each other - there is no hierarchy (even if it would look like it), just flat names of packages.

As to how you could circumvent that, I'd think the only way would be to iterate all packages and generate your java code based on that iteration. There is no straight way to do it.